# Is there a way to reference a particular element in a yaml array?

Tags: yaml, cross-reference, indirection

Is there a way to reference a particular element in a yaml array?
For example if I have this bit of yaml:

```
node_list:
  - one
  - two
  - three
```

Can I do something like this:

```
first_node: node_list[0]
```

Comment: YAML has no array construct. What you are looking at is called a sequence and that can be represented on loading in your programming language to something called differently. E.g. if you work with Python sequences are represented as `list`. If you talk about YAML generically and not in relation to some specific programming language, please use the appropriate terminology from the specification.

Comment: There are myriad flavors of data structures, but they can all be adequately represented with three basic primitives: mappings (hashes/dictionaries), sequences (arrays/lists) and scalars (strings/numbers). - http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Introduction

Comment: @RedCricket: The paragraph you refer to is read as: name of the primitive is **sequence**, which can represent array or list. Similarly: name of the (another) primitive is *scalar*, which can represent string or number. While in given case it is obvious that you talk about "sequences", notion of "array" in in other YAML context could be misleading.

Comment: Oh I thought it read as "There are myriad flavors of data structures, but they can all be adequately represented with three basic primitives: mappings (hashes/dictionaries), sequences (arrays/lists) and scalars (strings/numbers)". Maybe I need glasses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only with anchors & aliases. Example:

```
node_list:
  - &first one
  - two
  - three
first_node: *first
```

There is no equivalent to XPath in YAML, at least not officially.