# YAML - Assigning alias to anchor alternatives

Tags: yaml, alias, directed-graph

In YAML, we are not allowed to assign an alias to an anchor.  How can I acheieve similar functionality so that I can use one generic key throughout the YAML file while only needing to make an update in one location?

```
t_shirt_sizes:
  &t_shirt_xs EXTRA_SMALL
  &t_shirt_sm SMALL
  &t_shirt_md MEDIUM
  &t_shirt_lg LARGE
  &t_shirt_xl EXTRA_LARGE

t_shirt:
  &t_shirt_size *t_shirt_md


# Use the *t_shirt_size further down the YAML file

store:
  order_shirt_sizes: *t_shirt_size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible:

```yaml
t_shirt:
  &t_shirt_size EXTRA_SMALL
```

It fulfils your requirement to only need a single change to change the size everywhere. If you need the indirection, the closest thing you can do is

```yaml
t_shirt:
  &t_shirt_size [ *t_shirt_md ]
```

Then you'd need to handle the size value as 1-value sequence during loading.

YAML serializes a graph of directed nodes. Using an alias makes another connection to the referenced node, therefore does not create a new node and thus it cannot be anchored. The purpose of anchors & aliases is to be able to serialize cyclic graphs.

Comment: Noted and will give it a test.

Comment: I was not able to get your recommendation to work.  However, I found another question that you responded to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987134/is-there-a-way-to-reference-a-particular-element-in-a-yaml-array). So is it possible to reference `first_node` elsewhere in the file?

Comment: @user2715877 You can reference `first_node` with an alias. However you'd be referencing the scalar value `first_node`, not the mapping entry that has `first_node` as key. There is no way to query the value of `first_node` by referencing `first_node` with an alias. YAML is pure data and does not have any kind of query language or instructions.